# Merger with BrewAdvice

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The guys at BrewAdvice.com, the stackexchange 1.0 version of us, said (way back when we were in commitment phase) that they'd be all for merging with us.  They've built up a nice pile of answers, as well as an existing community.

From the sounds of things over there, this is going to happen:
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/meta-are-we-being-merged-into-the-other-stack-exchange-brew-site

Haven't heard anything official outside of brewadvice about this, but it makes sense.

Comment: Nice find. I didn't even realize this existed. I really wish I would have known though...

Comment: A friend pointed it out to me back when I was promoting HB.SE.  I think that there's a lot of value in bringing them in, since they've got a community and we've got a better platform.

Comment: My biggest question is what would be the logistics of this? I think it would be a great jumpstart for the site and both sites have similar DNA, but I wonder how trivial it will be to work through a merger. Having looked at the system dumps from other SE sites and my guess is that it should be very possible to pull the content in here, but I think we'd need some help/advice from meta.meta to understand how/if this might happen.

Comment: Awesome! Are any of their users (esp. moderators) in on the private beta?

Comment: @Nicholas Trandem : When the merger happens, there will be no more private beta. To avoid a disruption of service for their current users, we forgo the closed beta period.

Comment: @Nicholas - Yes, I'm one of their users :-)

Comment: We're heeeeeeere. Thanks for taking us on guys! We at BrewAdvice.com are excited to tackle the q&a with you all.

Comment: Ah crap- there goes the neighborhood.  :P

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as posted in their system message:

> BrewAdvice.com will be merged into the StackExchange 2.0 platform shortly. New look, new features, and hopefully no downtime.

The physical merging of the data is largely a technical issue which is being dealt with by our developers right now. If all goes well, expect the data to be merged in the next day or two.

Comment: Is this merger going on right now?  I see some new users on the site that have a lot of rep and seem to have a rep graph that goes back to earlier this year.  Any update on this merger would be nice.

Comment: The merger was completed today, pretty much as described here.